# Java ConcurrentSkipListMap: adding atomically another Collection object

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, concurrency, synchronization

I have a concurrent scenario where I have to write a lot to a sorted datastructure.

I thought about using ConcurrentSkipListMap for this reason. My definition is something like this: `ConcurrentSkipListMap<K, List<V>>`, which of course makes it quite difficult to manage insertions of the `List<V>` when the first element is inserted.

I.e.:

```
List<V> list = map.get(k);
if (list == null) {
    list = new LinkedList<V>();
    map.put(list);
}
list.add(v);
```

Of course this is not atomic. Using the class `putIfAbsent()` method would make it quite awkward and inefficient:

```
List<V> newElement = new LinkedList<V>();
List<V> previous = map.putIfAbsent(k, newElement);
if (previous != null) {
    previous.add(v);
} else {
    newElement.add(v);
}
```

One way is of course to create my own lock and protect a normal TreeMap, but as I have a real high write rate on this object, I'd prefer something designed specifically for it. Something like `collections.defaultdict` of python would be perfect, of course.

Comment: Do you know that using a locked or synchronized collection would be too slow?  How fast do you need it to be? (don't say as fast as possible ;)

Comment: I have basically just writes to this data-structure and concurrentskiplistmap is very efficient on this particular aspect, allowing a good level of concurrency on writes. With TreeMap/RBTree I'd be basically serial in the whole insert block.

Comment: Have you considered guava's MultiMap?

Comment: Have you tested whether it would make a measurable difference to your application? The reason I ask is that if you are doing 10 Million writes per second, it unlikely to make a measurable difference.  If you are doing 100 million writes per second, it would make a difference (and you would run out of memory pretty fast too)

Comment: @fge i guess what is more efficient, compared to John's solution: TreeMultiMap has to be synchronized externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.

First: The most effecient way to handle your the put-if-absent case is to do a pseudo double check

```
public void add(Object key, Object val) {
    List list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new LinkedList();
        List temp = map.putIfAbsent(list);
        if (temp != null)
            list = temp;
    }
    list.add(val);
}
```

That is as effecient as you can get for the put-if-absent case.

Second: You still have a concurrency issue here with adding to the list.  You may want to wrap the LinkedList in `Collections.synchronizedList()` before putting to the map.

```
public void add(Object key, Object val) {
        List list = map.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
            List temp = map.putIfAbsent(list);
            if (temp != null)
                list = temp;
        }
        list.add(val);
    }
```

Comment: yes, completely forgot to mention the `LinkedList` concurrency issue as it was out of the scope of the question, thanks!